# Using bash to print only some lines from a file

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I am trying to go through some log files and need to cut data from it for use in other software. The log files look like this:

```
Oct2614 status:ok 0.86.50.86
Oct2614 status:ok 0.111.122.11
Oct2714 status:ok 0.21.24.111
Oct2814 status:ok 0.15.121.12
Oct2814 status:ok 0.61.51.25

(IP addresses not real)
```

I want to print only one status code per day, so how could I print, for example, `Oct2614 status:ok 0.86.50.86` and ignore the second instance `Oct2614 status:ok 0.111.122.11`? Using bash would be best so that I can simply make an .sh out of it and use it in multiple places.

I have tried using `grep 'Oct2614' | uniq` but I am unfamiliar with bash commands.

Comment: And what did you try so far? This isn't code-writing website.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. Posted above.

Comment: do you want to allow for the case where you have `Oct ... status:error ...`? Please edit your question with this info, rather than responding here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{if (a[$1]++==0) print $0}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are always the same number of characters, use `uniq -w` to hide lines where the first 7 characters are the same as the previous line:

```
$ uniq -w7 log.txt
Oct2614 status:ok 0.86.50.86
Oct2714 status:ok 0.21.24.111
Oct2814 status:ok 0.15.121.12
```

If you want to search for the first entry from a particular date, try `grep -m` to limit the number of matches:

```
$ grep -m1 '^Oct2614'
Oct2614 status:ok 0.86.50.86
```